# issubset method different than subSet in superSet - Error in Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, subset

Why issubset method of sets in python3.x don't return the same than subSet in superSet ?

logically is correctly but the console return me unexpected result

works fine with shorts sets but large sets the (subSet in superSet) make mistakes

```py
def isStrictSuperset(superSet, subSet):          
    strictSuperset = False                      
     

    # condition1 = subSet.issubset(superSet)   # why this is difrent than de follow condition
    condition1 = subSet in superSet            # Error! incorrect result line 
    condition2 = superSet != subSet
    
    if condition1 and condition2:
        strictSuperset = True
        
    return strictSuperset                       # return if strict superset or not
            
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # list of string 
    superSet = input().split(' ')                  
    subSet = input().split(" ")

    # convert the list of string to set of integers
    superSet = set(int(x) for x in superSet)      
    subSet = set (int(x) for x in subSet)           

    
    # output
    print( isStrictSuperset(superSet, subSet) )
```

input:

```
51 28 10 61 99 31 55 7 88 48 18 80 18 36 49 21 36 1 49 53 11 78 46 87 82 28 76 50 89 31 14 81 87 39 3 69 26 18 85 18 23 43 75 5 64 47 34 19 2 54 92 45 79 80 59 16 75 80 55 24 56 74 76 31 22 74 20 93 79 81 12 57 21 79 65 32 57 37 47 84 82 28 72 15 53 50 86 58 83 88 3 44 76 63 32 14 13 38 29 70 38 4 71 15 45 4 94 24 46 6 95 48 15 82 92 62 6 67 38 20 60 78 37 84 32 39 51 88 13 99 6 3 64 37 83 68 18 51 98 37 11 48 63 97 30 90 73 44 63 25 78 12 25 91 36 38 59 12 36 51 58 61 82 91 31 41 36 99 28 50 28 64 22 56 26 39 75 53 8 41 94 86 35 69 48 17 80 32 12 29 2 33 51 79 58 74 91 46 6 54 66 0 75 60 30 95 57 36 70 32 83 1 88 27 57 2 67 28 18 51 61 16 40 79 96 78 27 72 85 45 73 12 89 31 11 24 42 94 22 84 1 67 8 62 80 77 81 58 1 6 63 30 64 37 44 60 11 14 68 28 81 86 30 17 81 14 30 44 64 89 7 94 89 13 59 88 34 42 6 51 10 19 66 91 46 22 41 34 98 4 26 90 84 90 44 90 84 13 36 6 97 21 30 52 46 15 83 89 45 83 33 11 3 18 6 82 17 23 13 91 27 39 76 11 86 12 97 64 51 48 84 35 66 15 48 32 99 11 18 93 11 85 71 63 57 76 1 80 45 19 7 39 80 70 78 3 17 51 14 99 47 83 17 82 23 59 59 41 77 22 7 35 22 98 59 90 80 72 60 67 22 75 3 99 18 81 47 48 18 98 18 37 47 65 98 86 82 5 30 87 25 17 97 60 93 33 99 89 62 98 40 27 70 57 49 93 46 11 38 94 43 75 61 75 55 45 26 9 84 89 40 87 14 61 31 99 53 6 83 55 15 95 46 8 58 73 58 57 9 7 49 21 31 88 31 32 61 30 19 69 78 33 3 0 70 73 40 91 91 96 72 79 0 41 91 51 10 80 50 77 30 38 1 85 56 90 78 36 31 0 82 12 95 28 1 65 72 75 89 54


81 79 97 20 68 23 19 12 53 86 26 36 4 64 10 43 12 75 98 30 12 33 27 1 32 68 64 49 99 10 16 9 7 47 23 29 30 94 57 25 38 15 57 33 79 28 45 98 20 50 34 93 6 14 9 29 56 13 44 67 5 23 32 38 78 20 55 35 25 91 64 10 47 32 97 44 85 65 87 36 91 88 78 6 48 86 67 56 44 18 98 39 10 80 47 65 49 98 63 21
```

output: `False`

expected output: `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subset in superset` checkes whether `subset` is an *element* of `superset`; i.e., it checks `∈`, not `⊆`.

You can simply use `<` to check whether a set is a proper subset of another: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset

```py
print({1, 2} in {1,2,3}) # False
print({1, 2} < {1,2,3}) # True
```

Comment: I wanted to know why it happened. But equal thanks for answering cool shortcut :) im new here